# Are 10 experiments measuring 1 random variable "similar" to 1 experiment measuring 10 independent random variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I have some teammates that like to "measure everything" and want to decrease confidence intervals. I'm trying to intuitively understand where things can go wrong with this approach.

Assuming a 90% confidence interval for statistical significance, I know (please correct me if I'm wrong) that if I take 10 samples (of, let's say 10,000 data points each), and for each sample measure the same random variable X, then 1 of these samples may report statistical significance though in reality this was by random chance.

In my situation, I have only 1 sample (of 10,000 data points) and 10 random variables that are being looked at. Assuming 90% confidence interval, and assuming that all random variables are independent, would it mean that (on average) 1 of these random variables reaches the wrong conclusion regarding statistical significance?

Comment: Exactly what kind of statistical significance are you expecting with one data point (per variable)?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone what do you mean one data point? It's one statistic, but the sample and control has some 10,000 data points.

Comment: You should edit your question and make clear that a "sample" means 10,000 data points. This is your first mention of 10,000. As written, the question says "I have only 1 sample and 10 random variables that are being looked at" - that sounds like sample means 1 data point, hence my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the 10 samples on the same random variable are independent.  Then the answer to your question is yes.

It's not necessary to assume independence of the samples. However if we don't, then the "average" may never occur.  For instance, assume perfect dependence of the 10 samples. Then with probability = 0.1, all samples will result in the wrong conclusion, and  with probability = 0.9, none of the  samples will result in the wrong conclusion.  The expected (i.e., mathematical expectation of) percentage of samples resulting in the wrong conclusion is 10%, yet there is 0 probability that 10% of the 10 samples will result in the wrong conclusion. To put it another way, the average (expected value) is the (a) minimum likelihood outcome.  This of course is an extreme example, but serves to make the general point about what can happen if the samples are not independent.

Comment: Thanks @mark. I understand the dependence vs. independence of the samples themselves. Are you saying then that under the scenario of 1 sample with 10 independent variables, 1 out of these variables is likely to report the wrong conclusion?

Comment: That depends what you mean by "likely". On average, 1 out of 10 samples will report the wrong conclusion, but if there are 10 independent samples, there's a a 0.9^(10) = 34.9% chance that there will be no wrong conclusions.

Comment: sorry to push again on this - you keep referring to "10 independent samples", which is what I could find in text books and fully understand, but it is also not my question.. In my situation (3rd paragraph in my question above) I only have 1 sample and 10 random variables pulled from it. Are you saying that both "1 sample, 10 variables" and "10 samples, 1 variable" have the same 34.9% chance of reporting wrong conclusion on 1 variable (assuming 10 variables are independent and 10 samples are independent) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. But note that the 34.9% figure only applies if the samples are independent.